# Why would my boss ask if I applied for jobs when trying to discuss a salary raise and issues within the company?

Tags: company

Why would my boss ask if I applied for jobs when trying to discuss a salary raise and issues within the company? Is there a reason for this? Is it a bad thing for him, for me? What am I missing, because I thought it was weird he would ask whether I had applied for a job or not. By the way, the company seems to be extremely reliant on me, but aren't willing to shell out money.

Comment: Maybe, the reason is that they know they do not pay you enough, and they want to see if you are looking for new jobs. If you are, then maybe, they will try to pay you more to match the market rate ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Workplace SE. Seems like a fair question from someone new to corporate life to me. It deserves a proper answer, but a quick one is that often seeking a raise and looking for new work go together. Some managers just prefer to ask straightforwardly, because it gives a lot of information about broader satisfaction with the job.

Answer (score 15):

There are a few reasons. They basically want to see:

- If you have potentially other job offers already
- If you're thinking about leaving
- If you have a fair understanding of your worth

I don't think it's a scare tactic as [Kilisi suggests](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/184292/59502), especially if the company is as reliant on you as you think. If they actually wanted to scare you, they would just say that you're easily replaced.

Comment: I had a superior who told me "Go look for jobs and try to find opportunities, it will be easier to negotiate for a bigger raise for you if you can prove that other companies are ready to pay more for you.".

Comment: @f222 Yeah. It's absolutely the case that sometimes the case that you manager is willing to go into bat for you, but they need help.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be to see how good your negotiating position is. If you're not applying to other jobs, your boss might think they can get away with paying you less. If you're already applying (and especially if you already have an offer) you'll have a much stronger position to negotiate (either your boss pays you more, or you leave). If you don't want to leave, you're more likely to accept less.

Of course all we can do is speculate. Only your boss knows the true reason they're asking.

Comment: When it comes down to it, the only leverage you really have is a willingness to walk away. Your salary is the price they pay to keep you from working somewhere else, or quitting. If you aren't willing to go elsewhere, they don't have much reason to pay you more.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of telling what your boss meant. But the implication is that you could end up unemployed. Especially if he didn't discuss the raise and other issues.

I would treat it as a scare tactic. My response would have been along the lines of 'No, not yet, but I need more money.' So the boss knows I'm serious and won't be intimidated by nonsense.

Comment: I honestly don't think necessarily a scare tactic.

Comment: "No, not yet, but I need more money", said the worker.  "I see. Don't we all need more money ?" replied the boss...   :-)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 yeah, but you just met a vague threat with another. The implication is that if your needs are not met you will soon be leaving. The implication is already there, but this underlines it. If that was the sum total of the bosses reply, I would be looking for another job. Because they either discuss properly or you're wasting time and looking weak and you'll still be asking for a raise next year.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, if I applied for a job elsewhere then I’m leaving. If the boss thinks he should pay me more if I applied elsewhere, then he should pay me more before I apply elsewhere. So the answer to the boss:

“You should pay me what I’m worth. I won’t tell anyone if I look for a job, applied for a job, or accepted a job until I give notice. If you are willing to pay me more for staying, then please do so.”

Answer (score 0):

One way to answer this kind of request, without losing potential negotiating power, is with a question of your own.

"Is the answer to this question relevant to the company's true value of my contributions?"

It's basically information poker, you are trying to gain insight to your opponent's hand without revealing your own.

Specifically use "us vs the company" language too, don't make it personal to your negotiating partner.

Great negotiators present options where both parties win. One way to ask for more compensation is by presenting it as improved future value due to your gained experience since you started.

"I've been here for 5 years now, and you know how much more effective I've become as I've learned the business. (insert some examples)

As long as I stay here, I'm going to continue to drive more and more business value for the company. It's time to evaluate my compensation based on my improved skill set and knowledge, as well as my projected growth over the next year."

Clearly you win if you get more money. What this does is make it clear that the *company wins by increasing your comp based on your output.*

Leave it unsaid that they could also *lose big by losing you.*